# asp.net SQL RadioButton Columns

Tags: asp.net, radio-button

```
  <div class="grid">
    <asp:GridView ID="gridView" CssClass="dataGrid" runat="server" SelectedRowStyle-BorderStyle="Double">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="radioBtn" CssClass="radioBtn" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

[image]

RadioButton one elect want but all choose as you can see in picture

Answer (score 0):

In order make only one radio button selectable on list of Radio Buttons you need to put them in a group like below:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text="1454" GroupName="Group1" />
        <br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text="1458" GroupName="Group1" />
        <br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" Text="1545" GroupName="Group1" />
        <br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton4" runat="server" Text="1578" GroupName="Group1" />
        <br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton5" runat="server" Text="1965" GroupName="Group1" />
        <br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton5" runat="server" Text="3954" GroupName="Group1" />
        <br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton7" runat="server" Text="6543" GroupName="Group1" />
        <br />
```

Once you group the radio button only one radio button in the group will be selectable.

Comment: data sql take one grain RadioButton there is

Comment: I could not understand can you explain it further?